# Transaction in pending state everytime

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to perform an operation but it is not getting executed

```
intkey set MyKey 99
```

Response after performing this

```
{
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8008/batch_statuses?id=59ce07c44962ed9ff56103909ab6f050bb8f4886651e5d3840a211b7604e215251448743d69362b6ee3479563d3f0967a76d5b7c63356b9e5206a0046913c341"
}
```

The Complete Response

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": "63c93b07c96199f13e493a7bd3b5fc38c281b2156868cf09b9f8165ed81704ae54dbcf5e9b42ca14a2bbf999cd3425824f9323208a18688fb0af05b9b2ec8f58",
"invalid_transactions": [],
"status": "PENDING"
}
],
"link": "http://127.0.0.1:8008/batch_statuses?id=63c93b07c96199f13e493a7bd3b5fc38c281b2156868cf09b9f8165ed81704ae54dbcf5e9b42ca14a2bbf999cd3425824f9323208a18688fb0af05b9b2ec8f58"
}
```

The Rest API SAYS

```
[2018-11-29 15:27:49.470 INFO helpers] POST /batches HTTP/1.1: 202 status, 348 size, in 0.004132 s
```

Settings TP

```
2018-11-29 15:27:08.987 INFO core] register attempt: OK
[2018-11-29 15:27:08.997 INFO handler] Setting setting 

sawtooth.settings.vote.authorized_keys changed from None to 03a42a2930130b5aea1c6e753bac90467d1e4c5a774fd4713ca80ef0fabac8a8f6
```

Instead of 200 i am getting 202 and i have waited a long time for it to get executed but it is still in pending state

Comment: Which docker compose file do you use?